# How to execute external commands from an Eshell script

Tags: eshell

I would like to create an elisp function such as

```
(defun script()
 (run "bash" "-c" "echo 1; sleep 3; echo 2")
 (eshell-print "Done"))
```

From an Eshell, its execution should look like:

```
eshell $ script
1
2
Done
eshell $
```

With the following requirements:

- the stdout of the bash process has to be "streamed" in the eshell buffer.
- it must be possible to `C-c` the script

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: I assume you want the script to execute synchronously as well, so you can expect it's done when the function returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the following Elisp code to your init files.

It contains a modified version of function `eshell-source-file`.
Essentially I changed `(insert-file-contents file)` to `(insert string)`.
Furthermore I needed a minor modification of `'eshell-command-name`.

It also contains the function `define-eshell-script` defining an Eshell command with a doc string and an Eshell script given by a string. The script takes care of the formalities for the script required by Eshell internals (e.g., correctly registering in the list variable `eshell-complex-commands`). Those formalities make the newly defined command interruptible.

```el
(require 'cl-lib) ;; for macro `cl-pushnew' (not autoloaded ?!)
(require 'esh-cmd) ;; for variable `eshell-complex-commands'

(defun eshell-source-string (string &optional args subcommand-p)
  "Execute a series of Eshell commands in STRING, passing ARGS.
Comments begin with `#'."
  (interactive "sString to be evaluated as eshell script: ")
  (let ((orig (point))
    (here (point-max))
    (inhibit-point-motion-hooks t))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (with-silent-modifications
      ;; FIXME: Why not use a temporary buffer and avoid this
      ;; "insert&delete" business?  --Stef
      (insert string)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (throw 'eshell-replace-command
             (prog1
                 (list 'let
                       (list (list 'eshell-command-name (list 'quote "source-string"))
                             (list 'eshell-command-arguments
                                   (list 'quote args)))
                       (let ((cmd (eshell-parse-command (cons here (point)))))
                         (if subcommand-p
                             (setq cmd (list 'eshell-as-subcommand cmd)))
                         cmd))
               (delete-region here (point))
               (goto-char orig))))))

(defun define-eshell-script (cmd doc string)
  "Define CMD as eshell script STRING with documentation DOC.
CMD can be a string or a symbol."
  (let ((fun (intern (concat "eshell/" cmd))))
    (fset fun
      `(lambda (&rest args)
        ,doc
        (eshell-source-string ,string args)))
    (cl-pushnew cmd (default-value 'eshell-complex-commands) :test #'equal)
    (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
      (with-current-buffer buffer
    (when (derived-mode-p 'eshell-mode)
      (cl-pushnew cmd eshell-complex-commands :test #'equal))))
    (put fun 'eshell-no-numeric-conversions t)))
```

If the above functions are available you can define your actual script with the help of `define-eshell-script` as follows.

```el
(define-eshell-script "script" "The doc-string: Output 1, sleep, and output 2."
   "bash -c \"echo 1; sleep 3; echo 2;\"
echo DONE")
```

The usage example in Eshell looks like you want it:

```
/Path/to/current/dir $ script
1
2
DONE
/Path/to/current/dir $
```

Comment: Thanks for this snippet!

But it is not possible to `C-c` the running process.

Comment: @lewo The script must be registered in `eshell-complex-commands` to be interruptible. The new function `define-eshell-script` does that for you. In that case the `eshell-replace-command` is cought by Eshell and one does not need `eshell-script-string` anymore. I've deleted it.

Comment: Hmm, it fails in my emacs :/

`$ script
No catch for tag: eshell-replace-command, (let ((eshell-command-name (quote "")) (eshell-command-arguments (quote nil))) (progn (eshell-commands (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "bash" (list "-c" (eshell-escape-arg "echo 1; sleep 3; echo 2;"))))) (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "echo" (list "DONE")))))`

Comment: Sorry about above formatting... I'm no longer able to edit it :/

Comment: Actually, I didn't have reloaded Eshell:/

Comment: @lewo The code was right but the usage was too complicated. You needed to run `define-eshell-script` before you run any Eshell (reloading Eshell did not help). I've written that in the answer but maybe you missed it. The `em-alias` module function `eshell-alias-initialize` makes `define-eshell-script` buffer-local. So the script was not registered in any already running Eshell. I've modified `define-eshell-script` such that it registeres the script in all already running Eshells. You do not need to care about running Eshells anymore when applying `define-eshell-script`.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a blast using eshell on MS Windows, even forgetting sometimes I am not on GNU/Linux, and I think I have two nice examples that some of you can relate to.

For console applications (your case):

```
(defun eshell/vbox-startvm-headless (name)
  "VBoxManage.exe startvm <vmname> --type headless"
  (let* ((cmdlist (list (shell-quote-argument (vboxmgr-path)) "startvm" name "--type" "headless")))
    (message (format "%S" cmdlist))
    (throw 'eshell-replace-command (eshell-parse-command (car cmdlist) (cdr cmdlist)))))

(add-to-list 'eshell-complex-commands "vbox-startvm-headless")
```

For GUI applications:

```
(defun eshell/virtualbox (&optional args)
  "VirtualBox.exe [args...]"
  (start-process "virtualbox" nil (virtualbox-path)))
```

The snippets above are from my `init.el` and they rely on `vboxmgr-path` and `virtualbox-path` to point to `VBoxManage.exe` and `VirtualBox.exe`, respectively.